# Multiple Springboot app refer to single git yaml

Tags: git, spring-boot

I need to create few springboot applications which have a common piece of functionality which is refer through a yml file over git (using Config server). I can have all applications to have the same property and use it accordingly but its a repetition of same property over multiple ymls. Is there a way where we can refer to a common yml file on git through multiple applications ?

I could not find a solution by myself.

Comment: have a look in the spring.io guides [centralized-configuration](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

Comment: thank you, i was able to make it work.